# Auto send error reports

Tags: 13.10

I am getting quite a lot of error reports (i guess i've messed up with nvidia drivers...) 
So, is there a way to auto send them? It's quite annoying to see all those messages, but I guess it's helpful for them to be sent!

Comment: Same issue. Hope it's possible...

Comment: I have searched for something helpful but sadly I cannot find a way to do this. It's not a major problem but if there were an option people would probably check the "Do this automatically from now" and loads of bug-report data would come in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recurring error. you should probably check the "Don't send reports of this type" check box on the dialog.  It will stop showing the message and will stop sending duplicate errors to them.

However, if it is one that does not give that option, you can disable it in apport entirely with these commands:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/apport
$ sudo restart apport
```

If you don't want to completely disable apport, they also point out you may be able to delete a crash file that is hanging around and causing the recurring problem with the following line:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Comment: `sudo gedit` doesn't work for me. I get an error `cannot open display: :0`. Using `gksudo` instead works. Also when inside gedit change it to `enabled=0`.